# Multiple TableView Custom Cells

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, cells

So i have created a table view with 2 custom cells.

i am trying to enter data into the 3rd cell, but im having a problem when returning how many cells & also to make my title array commence from my 3rd cell.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 3
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var row = indexPath.row

    if(row == sliderIndex){

        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! Row

        return cell

    }else if (row == instagramIndex) {

        var cell2 = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "instgramCell", for: indexPath) as! Insta

        return cell2

    } else {

        var cell3 = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "blogCell", for: indexPath) as! blogCell

        if (row == 3) {

            cell3.blogTitle.text = titleArray[0]

        }                       
        return cell3
    }
```

Comment: I guess that `sliderIndex = 0` and `instagramIndex = 1`? Then, `numberOfRows` is equal to `titleArray.count +2` and in your `else` case, just do `cell3.blogTitle.text = titleArray[row-3]` or something like that (could be an error of +1 or -1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In last case, row is impossible to equal to 3. Change it to 2.

You return 3 in `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int)`. So value of row only would be [0, 1, 2]

And according to your code, you might make a mistake that set `sliderIndex` to 1 and set `instagramIndex` to 2. They should be 0 and 1.